# Python: How to feed an RNN with Keras, sequential data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, sequential

I want to predict a binary outcome given a vector of data. I wanted to use keras for this task and was able to feed a simple network with it.

Input (features) was `X = [0, 1, 1, .... , 1, 0.5]` with `len(X) = 40`. and the target was `y = [0]` (or 1) a binary variable.

Now I realised, that the data has a time dimension. I can stack the X and would get a matrix with one dimension time and the other dimension the features.

For example:  `X = [[0,1,1,...,1,0.5],...,[0,0,1,...,1,0.5]]` and `y = [[0],...,[1]]`

My question is: Could I use a RNN or an LSTM network to feed the network the first timestep e.g. `X[:0]` with `y[:0]` and for timestep 2 (the network remembering the previous state)
`X[:1]` with `y[:1]` and so on until `X[:t]` and the target would be of form`y[:t]`. Time is not fixed, so `t` could be any integer (some max value exists).

Thank you for any answers:)

Comment: You definitely can. Read here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series for a very thorough explanation about how it works and how you need to shape your data to achieve what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks Massimo, it cerently was the right place to take a look at.